# Small, cheap processor with true 9 data-bit UART and drivers

Tags: processor, linux

In order to build a vending machine, using [Multi Drop Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidrop_bus) protocol, I need a board which will support a full 9 data-bit UART (with no bit stuffing, or tricks with the parity bit).

I also need a few GPIO for driving motors, and the ability to connect an LED dispaly.

Nice to have:

- also supporting WiFi
- supporting Linux
- large user support community
- good IDE
- programmable in C
- cheap

The 9 bit UART should preferably be on-board, but a simple add-on, such as an Arduino shield, would be acceptable.

I have seen a lot of purported solutions using bit-banging, but would rather do it properly, as any problems with bit-banging would not be much fun to debug.

---

[Update] Two years after originally posting, I wonder if anything new has appeared on the scene in the interim? Perhaps the idea of a shield/hat is the way to go?

Comment: If you can solder, see http://eliverse.com/content/vendiverse/

Comment: Or, even if you can't solder ... they are ***very*** helpful

Comment: Suddenly, after offering to post me a board, I get no reply to my emails, from several addresses at different domains; perhaps the project has been canelled :-(